# UserId is not displaying after successfull login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqlimport

I am new to codeigniter I Have create a login form and i am able to login succesfully fine and after login i am getting the login username also fine.but when i try to get the userid it is showing empty.I am displaying userid just like username displaying .But it is displaying empty why.Please any help would be appreciated thanks in Advance.

### This is my model

```
class Login_Model extends CI_Model{
public function checklogin($uname,$pass){
  $this->db->select('id','username','password');
  $this->db->get('login');
  $this->db->where('username',$uname);
  $this->db->where('password',$pass);
  $query=$this->db->get('login');
  if($query->num_rows()==1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }

}
```

### This is mycontroller

```
 public function verifyuser(){
    $name=$this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('Login_Model');
  if($this->Login_Model->checklogin($name,$password)){
    $this->Login_Model->checklogin($name,$password);
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $name);
    $this->session->set_userdata('id', $id);
    return true;
  }else{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyuser','username or password is invalid');
    return false;
  }

}
```

### This view

```
 $id= $this->session->userdata('id');
  echo "login id is".$id;
```

in View page i am accessing data like this but it giving empty for id but it is username fine.

Comment: it seems that you did not get the value of the id when you logged in so codeigniter doesn't know where to get where the value of $id in your block of code.

Comment: `$id` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just checking if the username and password match in the database in the `checklogin` function.

You are not returning the `id` and storing it in `$id` variable.

Hence since `$id` is undefined, no value is printed.

### Changes required

**Model**
Fetch the id from the database and return it instead of a boolean.

```
class Login_Model extends CI_Model{
    public function checklogin($uname,$pass){
        $this->db->select('id','username','password');
        $this->db->get('login');
        $this->db->where('username',$uname);
        $this->db->where('password',$pass);
        $query=$this->db->get('login');
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $res = $query->row_array();
            return $res['id'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**
Fetch the id and use it to set the userdata.

```
public function verifyuser(){
    $name=$this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('Login_Model');
    $id = $this->Login_Model->checklogin($name,$password);
    if($id){
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $name);
        $this->session->set_userdata('id', $id);
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyuser','username or password is invalid');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting userid but not storing it in session so you will not get this id

make model code like this

```
public function checklogin($uname,$password)
        {
               $this->db->select('user_id','user_email','user_password');
               $this->db->from('users');
               $this->db->where('user_email',$uname);
               $this->db->where('user_password',$password);
               $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
               if(!empty($res))
               {
                    return $res[0]['user_id'];
               }
               else
               {
                    return 0;
               }
}
```

and controller code like this so you will get id

```
$name=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $user_id=$this->Login_model->checklogin($name,$password);
        if($user_id > 0)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('id', $user_id);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyuser','username or password is invalid');
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following Changes in your Model.

```
class Login_Model extends CI_Model{
public function checklogin($uname,$pass){
   $query = $this->db->select('id','username','password');
          ->where(['username'=>$uname,'password'=>$pass]);
          ->get('login');

       return  $query->row()->id;  
}
```